# Filtering duplicates with AWK differing by timestamp

Tags: text-processing, deduplication

Given the list of files ordered by timestamp as shown below. I am seeking to retrieve the last occurrence of each file (the one at the bottom of each)

For example:

```
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-12-23-21-02.html
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-05-12-16.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-13-17-40.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
```

Would be something like:

```
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
```

Can I use awk or any other command to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example file the lines are **not** actually sorted by time. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` and `tac`

```
$ sed -En 'G;/^(([^-]*-){3}).*\n.*\n\1/d;H;P' <(tac input_file)
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
```

Comment: This also works (Linux only)
Thanks

Comment: Interesting way to de-duplicate **all** repeating lines. Most of the load is carried by the regex engine (which might become slow for long inputs).

Comment: This prints the first (last with `tac`) line found of each type. No matter if the input is sorted or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ tac file | awk '!seen[substr($0,1,length()-25)]++'
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK: the program saves the prefix of the previous file, gets the prefix of the current file and compares them, if the prefix has changed, then prints the previous file name.

```awk
# myuniq.awk

BEGIN {
    last_prefix = 0
    last_line = 0
}

{
    if (match($0, /(-[[:digit:]]+){6}\.html$/) == 0)
        next

    prefix = substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1)
    if (last_prefix != 0 && prefix != last_prefix)
        print last_line

    last_prefix = prefix
    last_line = $0
}

END {
    if (last_line != 0)
        print last_line
}
```

```
$ cat files.txt
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-12-23-21-02.html
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-05-12-16.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-13-17-40.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
$ awk -f myuniq.awk < files.txt
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
```

Comment: It works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split(/ "/" | [ <?after report> \- ]/);  \
            my %h.=append: [Z=>] @a>>[1], @a.map(*.[2]);  \
            for %h.sort {say (.key, .value.max).join("-")};'   file.txt
```

This answer simplifies the problem a bit, and assumes all files needing to be analyzed are in the same directory. So the directory is `split` off in the first step. Note, the code runs just fine if the directory is included (it just makes the `key` longer). Sample Output is returned in alphabetic "report" order:

Sample Input:

```
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-12-23-21-02.html
archive-daily/document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-05-12-16.html
archive-daily/document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-13-17-40.html
archive-daily/document-deb-report-2022-07-18-10-04-21.html
```

Sample Output:

```
document-deb-report-2022-07-18-13-17-40.html
document-loan-report-2022-07-18-17-07-26.html
document-sell-report-2022-07-13-23-15-34.html
```

In the first statement `lines` are read-in, destructively split on `/` solidus or at the `-` hyphen after the word "report", and stored in the `@a` array. A `%h` hash is declared, and three elements are `append`ed to the hash, each `[Z]` "Zip-reduction" pulled off their respective datastore and `=>` "fat-arrow" added in a key-value relationship. Hence the use of the composite `[Z=>]` metaoperator. Thus the first element becomes the `key` for the second element (`value`). Then a `max` value is computed, and the `join`ed result returned.

This is where it gets interesting. Raku has `ISO-8601` DateTimes built-in, so the second element can be `subst` substituted such that it is recognized as a `DateTime` object! So you can obtain the `max` of an actual `DateTime`:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split(/ "/" | [ <?after report> \- ]/);  \
            my %h.=append: [Z=>] @a>>[1], @a.map(*.[2].subst(/ \- (\d**2) \- (\d**2) \- (\d**2) \.html $/, {"T$0:$1:$2"} ).DateTime); \
            "".put; for %h.sort {say (.key => .value.max)};'  file.txt

document-deb-report => 2022-07-18T13:17:40Z
document-loan-report => 2022-07-18T17:07:26Z
document-sell-report => 2022-07-13T23:15:34Z
```

More info below. Please note that the `max` DateTimes are returned, per report. It's just the OP data that's out of order (as noted by @QuartzCristal).

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap#Mutable_hashes_and_immutable_maps
[https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-[]_(reduction_metaoperators)](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-%5B%5D_(reduction_metaoperators))
https://docs.raku.org/type/DateTime
https://raku.org